# EntityNotFoundException in Hibernate Many To One mapping however data exist

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm getting an error

> Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find tn.entities.AgenceBnq with id 01

when I get AgenceBnq through Employee

`Employee` class:

```
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
@NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findById", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.employeMat = ?1"),

public class Employee implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_MAT", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 15)
private String employeeMat;
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "AGENCE_COD")
private AgenceBnq agenceBnq;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="AGENCEBNQ")

public class AgenceBnq implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="AGENCE_COD", unique=true, nullable=false, length=10)
private String agenceCod;

...
//bi-directional many-to-one association to Employee
@OneToMany(mappedBy="agenceBnq")
private Set<Employee> employees;
}
```

I'm calling namedQuery Employee.findById in DAO to retrieve data and I have to get AgenceBnq from Employee but get this error while calling `query.getResultList()`

`@NotFound( action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)` isn't useful for me because data exist in AGENCEBNQ table and I have to retrieve date through `Employee`.

Is this a bug in hibernate ? I'm using hibernate version 3.6.7.Final

Comment: Why is it `e.employeMat = ?1` and not just `e.employeMat = ?`?

Comment: I'm always using `?1` for parameters and it works fine, even with `e.employeMat = ?` I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You dont need query for it, the EnityManger.find(Employee.class, YOUR_ID) will do the job.

Secondly dont use ? in your queries but names (e.employeMat = :id) as it is easier to debug and less error prones for complicated queries.

Finally, check your DB table if the AGENCE_COD column in Employee table really contains the valid ID for your entitity that crashes (and that it length matches the ID length of AgenceBnq). It should work, the typical reason why it doesnt will be that your Employe.AGENCE_COD has defualt value and when creatubg the new EMploye you add it only to the Agence but you did not set Agence in the Employ.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I did all of your recommandations but I'm not creating Employe I'm just Selecting data from dataBase and I still have the same problem

Comment: I am not saying that you creating I am saying that when the Employee was created it was not saved correctly. Not only the Agency has to exists but it has to be correctly referenced in the employee table (do you have foreign keys constrains in your db ?)

Comment: yes I have foreign keys constraints and the agence is well referenced in the database,

Comment: I have no clue then, it should work or I am blind and missing somehtign obvious. The only weird lookig thing is the string represention of ids for numbers (01) instead of (1), but if the mapping was wrong you should get sql error. Do you have read rights for both tables for your connection, and finally are your connected to the same DB you are checking manually. .